# Swift CoreData storing Ints and retrieving them

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to store an `Int` and then read it on the home screen view controller.

Here is what I'm doing

1. Passing the value to the final view controller where I also want to call a function to store the data

   ```
   var gameScore = [NSManagedObject]()

   func doSomething() {
       if let myData = yourFinishScore {
           // proving I passed score
           print("Your score is \(myData)")


           self.finishLabel.text = "\(myData)"

           //call function to save data
           saveName(myData)
       } else {
           // no data was obtained
           print("No Data")
       }
   }


   //

   func saveName(score: Int) {
       //1
       let appDelegate =
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

       let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

       //2
       let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Scores",
           inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

       let yourScore = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
           insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

       //3
       yourScore.setValue(score, forKey: "famousGuy")

       //print proves it's in thier correct
       print("your score is\(yourScore)")

       //4
       do {
           try managedContext.save()
           //5
           gameScore.append(yourScore)
           print("worked, I saved")
       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }
   ```
2. The navigating back to the 1st screen and trying to call the data back

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       //1
       let appDelegate =
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

       let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

       //2
       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Scores")

       //3
       do {
           let results =
           try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
           famousGuysScore = results as! [NSManagedObject]
           } catch let error as NSError {
               print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
           }
       }


       if famousGuysScore.count > 0 {
           print("There are objects")
           self.myScore.text = "\(famousGuysScore[0])"
       } else {
           print("No objects")
       }
   ```

I assume somewhere along the line I'm not saving the data correctly. I think the smoking gun is to do with `gameScore.append(yourScore)`, I must be doing something wrong here.

**UPDATE**

Pretty certain I am just doing something wrong with the `NSFetch`, Assume I need to iterate over what I've fetched to pull out the attribute

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what happens?

Comment: My issue is, I don't know if the score gets saved, just realised I don't even need the append. If I print famousGuysScore after the fetch it retrieves data but it's listed as data: <fault>, so assuming I've saved it wrong somewhere

Comment: Faults are (generally) nothing to worry about - just CoreData "lazy loading" to conserve memory.  Go ahead and extract the attribute values with `famousGuysScore[0].valueForKey("famousGuy")`.

Comment: That did the trick, issues was just using the data correctly from the fetch. Thanks